# Scatter chart duplicates same values on x-axis

Tags: php, ajax, google-visualization, scatter-plot

i'm drawing a scatter chart using ajax call. Some of values are duplicate on x-axis while y-axis values are different. Example -

```
{
            "cols": [
                    {"id":"","label":"Sold Year","pattern":"","type":"string"},
                    {"id":"","label":"Unit Price","pattern":"","type":"number"}
                ],
            "rows": [{"c":[{"v":"2006","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2007","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2008","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2009","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2010","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2015","f":null},{"v":"10700","f":"$10,700"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2015","f":null},{"v":"1280","f":"$1,280"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2016","f":null},{"v":"2500","f":"$2,500"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2016","f":null},{"v":"80500","f":"$80,500"}]},]}
```

In above example values for years on x-axis are duplicate (Year 2015 & 2016). The scatter chart draws 2 points for 2015 & same for 2016.
[image]
I want to show single x-axis value with different y-axis values.

The chart out put should be like -
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have two values inside json for 2015 and 2016 and hense it's repeated

Comment: @AlivetoDie Can you please help me format the json as per my requirement ?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the part, which you don't want?

Comment: "rows": [{"c":[{"v":"2015","f":null},{"v":"10700","f":"$10,700"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2015","f":null},{"v":"1280","f":"$1,280"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2016","f":null},{"v":"2500","f":"$2,500"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2016","f":null},{"v":"80500","f":"$80,500"}]},]}

Answer (score 0):

Rows have two entries for 2015 and 2016.

```
    "rows":
        [{"c":[{"v":"2006","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":
[{"v":"2007","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2008","f":null},
{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2009","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":
[{"v":"2010","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011","f":null},
{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":
[{"v":"2013","f":null},{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014","f":null},
{"v":"0","f":"$0"}]}, <Repeated part starts here -------{"c":[{"v":"2015","f":null},{"v":"10700","f":"$10,700"}]},
{"c":[{"v":"2015","f":null},{"v":"1280","f":"$1,280"}]},{"c":
[{"v":"2016","f":null},{"v":"2500","f":"$2,500"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2016","f":null},
{"v":"80500","f":"$80,500"}]} ------Repeated part ends here>]}
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i arrange the json which can support the format with google chart and it will meet my requirement ? Can you give example or format my json ?

Comment: Refer google chart json format from here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

Comment: two parameter in the row, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kindly Try this,

```
"rows": [{"c":[{"v":"2006","f":0}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2007","f":0}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2008","f":0}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2009","f":0}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2010","f":0}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2011","f":0}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2012","f":0}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2013","f":0}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2014","f":0}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2015","f":1280}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"2016","f":80500}]}
        ]
```

Kindly refer the below mentioned link, [js fiddle working file](https://jsfiddle.net/qLggc24q/)

Comment: On js fiddle you are drawing the chart without ajax. So it has normal array and it works. I'm trying to draw chart with ajax which has json format. The above json is not properly formatted.

Comment: which code you are asking ? the code from js fiddle ? or json that you asked to try ?

Comment: Hi,now i change some changes so please try again and let me know any query regarding this.

Comment: bro, you have removed the duplicate data. My requirement is to display data with duplicate values on y-axis but singe value on x-axis.

Comment: if we use duplicate data, conflict occurs, so kindly avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the json format in ajax response in following way -

```
[["Sold Year","Unit Price"],[2006,0],[2007,0],[2008,0],[2009,0],[2010,0],[2011,0],[2012,0],[2013,0],[2014,0],[2015,10700],[2015,1280],[2016,2500],[2016,80500]]
```

Now it is working as expected. Thank you all for your suggestions.